# How to transfer data from old HDD to new HDD for PS3 Super Slim?

Tags: ps3, hardware, hard-drive

I'm thinking of upgrading my PS3 HDD to a newer one, but so far I've seen tutorials on how to change the HDD but no information on how to transfer the games and data from my old HDD into the new one.

What are the tools I need to transfer the data from my old HDD? Do I need a computer? Do I need a USB drive? I just want to save myself the time of downloading all of the games from my HDD into the new one. I've never done a HDD upgrade on my PS3 and I don't want to ruin my console or anything by following steps that aren't for my needs.

Comment: If you google this there should be a fairly large handful of walkthroughs on this... At least there were back when I did it.

Comment: I'm finding how to change the HDD but haven't found something that tells me how to pass the data or a list of options for what I want, some even give homebrewing tips but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, I can't remember what I did for PS3, but for my PS4 there is a "backup saves" (or something) option in the save data management area. From there you just put it on a external drive and then put it back on your new one when finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a post I found from a quick online search](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-Support/How-do-I-transfer-data-from-one-PS3-hard-drive-to-another/td-p/43209290). It's been many years since I've done it, but it looks right from what I remember. There are a couple methods, but I'd focus on the simplest (the first option: Backup utility). I will also repost the steps, but there are images in that link that could be helpful, along with some extended discussion.

Your life will be a whole lot easier if you already have an external drive that is large enough for everything you need to transfer. Otherwise you'll probably have to use method 2 and keep track of many smaller devices instead (avoid this if possible). You do not need to use a separate computer or any special software.

**Method 1:** *Using the backup utility*

1. Go to (Settings) > (System Settings)
2. Go to [Backup Utility]
3. You will be given three options:
   a. **Backup**: Back-up all data from the PS3 hard disk drive to an external storage device.
   b. **Restore**: Use a back-up that was made to an external storage to restore data to the PS3 hard disk drive.
   c. **Delete Backup Data**: Erase backup data.
4. Select the option you wish to use.
   Make sure the external storage device has enough space to store all the data from your PS3 system.
   Note: Back-ups cannot be made to CD-R or other optical disc media.

**Method 2:** *Manually copying data from the PS3HDD to storage media*

5. Connect your removable storage media (USB storage device, MemoryStick, SD Memory Card, or CompactFlash, etc.) via the appropriate slot/port) to the PS3 system.
6. From the XMB home menu, you will need to specify which folder you prefer to copy information from (i.e. music, photos, games, videos, etc.)
7. Once you choose the file you want to copy, highlight the file and press triangle.
8. This will bring up a menu with three options: Copy, Delete, and Information.
   Select [Copy]
9. Select the destination. The file will begin to transfer to your removable media. You will be given a status screen that will show you the copy progress.
10. You will then be taken to a page that states, "Copy Complete".
11. To verify your transfer was successful, you may highlight the removable storage media, press the Triangle button and select "Display All". This will show you all of the files on the removable storage media. You may also insert your media into another system (PC, PSP® portable entertainment system) and view the files that way.

Whichever method you choose, **always** double check that **everything** you want to back up has been backed up. I cannot stress this enough... The last thing you want to find out when your new HDD is all set up and running is that your save files for Duke Nukem Forever weren't copied over.

Comment: Missing Duke Nukem saves? Are you speaking from experience, @DangerZone?

Comment: @T.J.L. - Haha, actually I never got the "pleasure" of playing that. Just the first game that comes to mind as a complete joke. I would Imagine that game goes for under $5 pretty much everywhere online...

Comment: thanks, I didn't know you could use an external HDD, most of the guides I've found involved the second method which made me feel really insecure about the whole deal, I'll pick up the HDD later this week and wish me luck, I got too many precious save files I can't be missing